# Possible bug in "unanswered" filter

Tags: bug, status-bydesign

Possible bug in "unanswered" filter: As shown in the screen capture below, the url says "unanswered", but the page content disagrees.

I don't think this is a browser problem, as I replicated this problem on a different machine (actually vmware linux). And the bug is persistent.

[image]

Comment: Just because something's status-bydesign doesn't mean that design makes sense. While this isn't a bug, it is a UX failure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not a bug; however, the language used is a bit confusing, IMHO. A post is considered "unanswered" when it doesn't have any upvoted answers.

In other words, as soon as one of the answers is up voted, the post will no longer appear in the unanswered filter.

Answer (score 4):

The Stack Exchange definition of unanswered questions is questions with *no upvoted answers*. Check the link's tooltip ;)

Comment: Thank you for the clarification (I _think!_). But I can't find your mentioned tooltip. The `no answers` option, which I ***now*** realize is totally different from `unanswered`, _does_ have a tooltip, stating the obvious. But is there a second one?

Comment: @JosephQuinsey You'll find the tooltip if you hover over the "unanswered" link in the questions page, it's the last link to the right, after "newest", "featured", "faq", "votes", "active".

Comment: Thank you--I found it. But I think there is still a bug, albeit a more minor one, for three reasons. Firstly, here are _two_ clickable `Unanswered` buttons, the first being after `Badges`, and this first one _does not_ provide the tooltip. And secondly, if you click it, it takes you to a page with `UNANSWERED QUESTIONS` displayed prominently. And finally thirdly, the tooltip itself is obviously ridiculous--either it or the button should be changed.

Comment: **Edit:** This is to clarify my 3rd point. I love SE. But saying the `Stack Exchange definition of unanswered questions is questions with _no upvoted answers_` is ridiculous--SE should not try to redefine the English language. (But getting a good label for a button is often hard.)

Comment: @JosephQuinsey - maybe you should pose the question of "what is the definition of an _unanswered question_?" to english.SE.  :-)